# Visual FoxPro 9 Grid: how to simulate down arrow with a barcode reader

Tags: datagrid, ascii, visual-foxpro

I have a grid in Visual FoxPro where my customer will use an Motorola CS3000 SERIES
Barcode Reader. The problem is the grid, if you simulate the Enter key (CHR(13)), is going to the next field on the same row and not make a new line.

The only way is to press the down arrow (which it seems impossible), and already tried with Vertical Tab, with Line Feed / carriage return, and with ALT+025 (Down Arrow character) with no luck.

Do you have idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the [Keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ks92c5bk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) command, with the *DNARROW* value?

Comment: As Doug said:

Keyboard '{DNARROW}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand than the Barcode reader simulate an Enter but not a keyboard command (DNARROW), isn't it? 
So that the solution should be picking the key pressed from the form, I thing there is s "keypress" form event, in that event you can put the code for skipping to the next record.